# Simplifying expression trees

Tags: algorithm, symbolic-math, algebra

I am trying to write a program that simplifies mathematical expressions.

I have already written a parser that converts a string to a binary tree.
For example (1+2)*x will become

```
    *
   / \
  +   x
 / \
1   2
```

The idea I had of simplifying such trees is as follows:
You store a set of trees and their simplified version
For example

```
    *                       +
   / \                     / \
  a   +        and        *   *
     / \                 / \ / \
    b   c               a  b a  c
```

(Where a,b,c can be any subtree)
Then, If I find a subtree that matches one of the stored trees, I will
replace it with its simplified version.

If necessary I will repeat the process until the tree is fully simplified.

The problem with this approach is that it can't "combine like terms" in some cases.
For example, if I try to store the tree:

```
      +                *
     / \      and     / \
    x   x            2   x
```

Then when I try to simplify the expression x+y+x, with the following tree:

```
    +
   / \
  x   +
     / \
    y   x
```

It will not be simplified to 2x+y, because the subtree

```
      +     
     / \     
    x   x
```

Is not contained in the tree, thus the tree will not be simplified.

I tried writing an explicit algorithm that combine like terms but there are too many
cases to consider.

Can anyone please help me find a solution to this problem?

Comment: The most common way to handle this is to hand code a bunch of heuristics into the simplification of `+` and `*`, but the right way to do this is, perhaps, to allow for backtracking, and a way to compare expressions for preferability, if two or more simplified forms are found. You will want to be able to enumerate the possible paths from the initial expression to a simplified form, allowing for backing up and going down a different path if you don't find anything applicable (this is the backtracking part).

Comment: Not every operation is going to lead to anything; in the absence of guidance (i.e., heuristics), all you can do is try all the rules you know and see if anything makes a difference after several steps. The point of the enumeration + backtracking + preference evaluation is to formalize that process.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of the basic ideas which is used in computer algebra systems.

For operators like `Plus` (+) and `Times` (*) you can define attributes like `Flat` ([associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)) and `Orderless` ([commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)). Also don't define `Plus` and `Times` as "binary" operators but as "multiple-argument" operators.

So an input like:

```
Plus(x,Plus(y,x))
```

in the first step can be transformed (flattened) because of the `Flat` attribute to

```
Plus(x,y,x)
```

in the next step it can be transformed (sorted) because of the `Orderless` attribute to

```
Plus(x,x,y)
```

In your "evaluation" step you can now go through the arguments and "simplify" the expression to:

```
Plus(Times(2,x),y)
```

This approach has the advantage that expressions which are "structural equal" are stored in the same "canonical form" and could for example easier compared for "object equality" in the used programming language.

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach. I created the "non-binary tree" as you suggested but instead of sorting the operands and transforming the tree back to a binary tree, I wrote an algorithm that merges similar terms explicitly in the "non-binary tree". Is your approach better?

Comment: I edited the answer for the "advantage of the approach"

Answer (score 1):

We may consider polynomials

we get the `'+'-reducer` and `'*'-reducer` for two polynomes in `X`

Now in the tree, instead of considering either a scalar or `x` as node, we may consider an "irreducible" polynomial.

Then we apply the `'*'-reducer` if the node operator is `*` or `'+'-reducer` otherwise which both transform two irreducibles polynome as an new irreducible one.

e.g where `P_a`, `P_b` two polynomes and

```
P_a = {
  x0: 1 // term of degree 0 idem 1
  x1: 2 // 2x
  x3: 4 // 4x^3
}
```

and `P_b = {x1: 3}`

we get for sum: `P_a + P_b = {x0: 1, x1: 5, x3: 4}`

(so tree `['+', P_a, P_b]` simplifies as `{x: 0, x1: 5, x3: 4}`)

we get for multiplication: `P_a * P_b = {x1: 3, x2: 6, x3: 12}`

At the end of the day, we get an irreducible polynome in `X`.

We can write back that polynome as a binary tree (which is thus a simplified tree):

for each monome (in `X^i`), write its associated binary tree (which only contains `*` operator)
e.g: `5x^3 => ['*', ['*', ['*', x, x], x], 5]`
then sum them
e.g: `1 + x + x^2 => ['+', 1, ['*', x, 1], ['*', x, x]`

Same idea (idem implementing `'+'-reducer`/`'*'-reducer`) can be applied with an expression having polynomes in `X`, `Y` or `Z`, or whatever (so in your case, `x`, `y`)

below an example of implementation (you may uncomment and pass the tests using nodejs)

```js
// a, b are polynomes of form {monomialKey: scalar, monomialKey2, scalar2, ...}
// a monomial key is e.g x1y2z2
const add = (a, b) => {
  const out = Object.assign({}, a)
  Object.entries(b).forEach(([monomialKey, scalar]) => {
    out[monomialKey] = (out[monomialKey] || 0) + scalar
    if (out[monomialKey] === 0) {
      delete out[monomialKey]
    }
  })
  return out
}
// transforms x1y2z2 to {x: 1, y: 2, z: 2}
const parseKey = s => s.match(/[a-z]+\d+/g).reduce((o, kv) => {
  const [,varname,deg] = kv.match(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/)
  o[varname] = parseInt(deg)
  return o
}, {})
const writeKey = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((s, [varname, deg]) => s + varname+deg, '')

// simplify monomial, e.g x1y3*x1 => x2y3
const timesMonomialKey = (iA, iB) => {
  const a = parseKey(iA)
  const b = parseKey(iB)
  const out = {}
  ;[a,b].forEach(x => Object.entries(x).forEach(([varname, deg]) => {
    if (deg === 0) return
    out[varname] = (out[varname] || 0) + deg
  }))
  if (Object.keys(out).length === 0) return writeKey({ x: 0 })
  return writeKey(out)
}
// a, b both polynomes
const times = (a, b) => {
  const out = {}
  Object.entries(a).forEach(([monimalKeyA, sA]) => {
    Object.entries(b).forEach(([monimalKeyB, sB]) => {
      const key = timesMonomialKey(monimalKeyA, monimalKeyB)
      out[key] = (out[key] || 0) + sA * sB
      if (out[key] === 0) {
        delete out[key]
      }
    })
  })
  return out
}


const reduceTree = t => { // of the form [operator, left, right] or val
  if (!Array.isArray(t)) {
    return typeof(t) === 'string'
      ? { [writeKey({ [t]: 1 })]: 1 } // x => {x1: 1}
      : { [writeKey({ x: 0 })]: t }  // 5 => {x0: 5}
  }
  const [op, leftTree, rightTree] = t
  const left = reduceTree(leftTree)
  const right = reduceTree(rightTree)
  return op === '+' ? add(left, right) : times(left, right)
}
const writePolynomial = o => {
  const writeMonomial = ([key, s]) => {
    const a = parseKey(key)
    const factors = Object.entries(a).flatMap(([varname, deg]) => {
      return Array.from({length: deg}).fill(varname)
    }).concat(s !== 1 ? s : [])
    return factors.reduce((t, next) => ['*', t, next])
  }
  if (Object.keys(o).length === 0) return 0
  return Object.entries(o).map(writeMonomial).reduce((t, next) => ['+', t, next])
}
console.log(writePolynomial(reduceTree(['+', ['+', 'x', 'y'], 'x'])))
//const assert = require('assert')
//assert.deepEqual(parseKey('x0y2z3'), { x: 0, y: 2, z: 3 })
//assert.deepEqual(writeKey({ x: 0, y: 2, z: 3 }), 'x0y2z3')
//assert.deepEqual(timesMonomialKey('x1y2', 'x3z1'), 'x4y2z1')
//assert.deepEqual(timesMonomialKey('x0y0', 'z0'), 'x0')
//assert.deepEqual(timesMonomialKey('x0y0', 'z0x1'), 'x1')
//assert.deepEqual(add({x0: 3, x1: 2}, {x0: 4, x3: 5}), {x0: 7, x1: 2, x3: 5})
//assert.deepEqual(add({x0: 3, y1: 2}, {x0: 4, y2: 5}), {x0: 7, y1: 2, y2: 5})
//assert.deepEqual(add({x0: 1}, {x0: -1}), {})
//assert.deepEqual(times({x0: 3, x1: 2}, {x0: 4, x1: 5}), {x0: 12, x1: 23, x2: 10})
//assert.deepEqual(times(
//  {x1y0: 3, x1y1: 2},
//  {x1y0: 4, x1y1: 5}),
//  {x2: 12, x2y1: 23, x2y2: 10}
//)
//assert.deepEqual(reduceTree('x'), {x1: 1})
//assert.deepEqual(reduceTree(['*', 2, 'x']), {x1: 2})
//assert.deepEqual(reduceTree(['+', 2, 'x']), {x0: 2, x1: 1})
//assert.deepEqual(reduceTree(['+', 'x', ['+', 'y', 'x']]), {x1: 2, y1: 1})
//assert.deepEqual(writePolynomial({ x1y1:1, x1y2: 2}), ['+', ['*', 'x', 'y'], ['*', ['*', ['*', 'x', 'y'], 'y'], 2]])
//assert.deepEqual(writePolynomial(reduceTree(['*', ['*', 'x', 'y'], 0])), 0)
//assert.deepEqual(writePolynomial(reduceTree(['+', ['*', ['*', 'x', 'y'], 0], 2])), 2)
//
//// finally your example :)
//assert.deepEqual(writePolynomial(reduceTree(['+', ['+', 'x', 'y'], 'x'])), ['+', ['*', 'x', 2], 'y'])
```