# Symbolic calculator symbol representation structure

Tags: symbols, symbolic-math

I am trying to make a small program, that could do symbolic calculations. Nothing more complex than the five basic operations (sum, subtraction, multiplication, division and exponentiation). These things seem simple on paper, but I found that to get the computer to understand how to do these calculations is pretty hard.

And now the question is, how to represent a symbol so that it can be calculated on easily?

I have tried the following:
Numbers are rationals with numerical (integer) numerator and denominator. The rest are symbols with labels (x, y), and they have counts that consist of other symbols and rationals in the sense, that the symbols that are summed together are in an array, and symbols that are multiplied together are the counts of symbols. Thus `(x+y)*z` becomes symbol z with counts of [symbol x, symbol y], and `x*y*z` becomes symbol z with count of [symbol y with count of [symbol x]].

Addition is simple, if the other symbols label matches, then add the two counts together:
`3x+yx` => symbol x with count of [rational 3/1, symbol y]

Subtraction is as simple as addition, just add rational of negative number to the other:
`3x+(-yx)` => symbol x with count of [rational 3/1, symbol y with count of [rational -1/1]

Multiplication gets harder, but for every element of symbols count, add to their count the multiplier:
`(1+y)x * z` => symbol x with count of [symbol z, symbol y with count of [symbol z]]

Division is something I didn't get to, because how to find if something is divisible is actually hard, as there is need to find for every element of symbols count if it is divisible, including the original symbols count, and then find where can the eliminations be made.

So at this point I am a bit lost, and would like to know if there is a reasonably good way of representing symbols in symbolic calculations. Am I doing something right, or is this mess going to end up messier if I continue.

I also tried working with binary trees, but the division became too hard there as well.

Would it make more sense to represent the symbols as strings of characters, and try to do character by character computation? If yes, then how would division once again work, especially if there are fractions involved?

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293460/24819. Try representing division as "multiplication with the inverse value" and subtraction as "addition with the negated value".

Comment: Sounds like you are on a good path. Take a look at the question linked by axelck, it's very relevant. You might consider working with Lisp (Common Lisp or Scheme) since Lisp has symbols as first-class objects, and in fact Lisp was originally devised in part to work on problems such as this.